# Rails 4.1.1 Postgres app with Mysql Legacy database Import

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I've been building a rails app using a postgres database but of course I also have been tasked with importing data from a legacy mysql database.

The way I've been handling this so far:

```
# config/database.yml
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 10
  username: myuser
  password:

legacy_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myapp_legacy
  pool: 10
  username: myuser
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# app/models/legacy.rb
class Legacy < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "legacy_#{Rails.env}".to_sym

  def self.import
    self.find_each do |object|
      imported_model = object.class.model.new object.attribute_map
      object.report_failures unless imported_model.save
    end
  end

  def self.import_all
    Rails.application.eager_load!
    self.subclasses.each {|subclass| subclass.import }
  end
end

# app/models/legacy/chapter.rb
# a bunch of different subclasses like this
class Legacy::Chapter < Legacy
  self.table_name = 'chapters'

  def self.model
    'Chapter'.constantize
  end

  def attribute_map
    {
      id: id,
      name: name,
      body: chapterBody
    }
  end
end
```

Then I have a rake task that runs `Legacy.import_all`. A lot of this was stolen from [this post](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2012/09/21/establishing-a-connection-to-a-non-default-database-in-rails-3-2-2/).

There's a few things wrong with this:

The main problem is, when i run `Legacy.import_all` it makes it through about half of the tables then I get an error like:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'import' for Legacy::SomeSubclass(Table doesn't exist):Class`

I think this is because we just have too many connections in the pool. It seems though like it is looking for the `SomeSubClass table_name` from within the postgres database, but it should be looking on the mysql database.

This is probably because of the methods like:

```
  def self.model
    'Chapter'.constantize
  end
```

in the above subclass.  I am doing it like that instead of:

```
  def self.model
    Chapter
  end
```

because I have a normal model (non-legacy) in my app also called Chapter and I was running into scoping issues there as well.

Anyways this is a huge mess and any thoughts about where I should dig would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I guess something related with same name of Legacy class and Legacy module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try prefixing subclass.import with ::

```
def self.import_all
  Rails.application.eager_load!
  self.subclasses.each {|subclass| ::subclass.import }
end
```

Comment: no dice, you seemingly can't add the `::` prefix to a class when that class is a variable, as in `::subclass.import`. I just get an error: `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting tCONSTANT self.subclasses.each {|subclass| ::subclass.import }`. I wonder if I should add `::` instead of `constantize` to all the models that use it.

Comment: Try `Kernel.const_get("#{subclass}").import`

Comment: no dice, same error.  Hmm. I feel like there might be too many connections in the pool?